# using AppDomain.DoCallBack() asynchronously

Tags: c#, appdomain

I am trying to call DoCallBack for multiple AppDomains, but it is not asynchronous. Is there a way to make the calls asynchronous? Here is what I am attempting to do:

```
        var appDomain1 = System.AppDomain.CreateDomain("event1");
        var appDomain2 = System.AppDomain.CreateDomain("event2");

        Console.WriteLine("Executing appDomain1");
        appDomain1.DoCallBack(new CrossAppDomainDelegate(Event));
        Console.WriteLine("Executing appDomain2");
        appDomain2.DoCallBack(new CrossAppDomainDelegate(Event));
```

I am attempting to execute the method "Event" in multiple appDomains asynchronously.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the TPL, and call DoCallBack from a Task:

```
var task1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => appDomain1.DoCallBack(Event));
var task2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => appDomain2.DoCallBack(Event));
Task.WaitAll(task1, task2);
```

Answer (score 3):

Although it may suite your needs just fine, DoCallBack is a bit limited. Consider this instead (also works in parallel):

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    using System;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using AppDomainToolkit;

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var context1 = AppDomainContext.Create())
            using (var context2 = AppDomainContext.Create())
            {
                var task1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(
                    () =>
                    {
                        RemoteAction.Invoke(
                            context1.Domain, 
                            () => 
                            {
                                var appName = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ApplicationName;
                                Console.WriteLine("Hello from app domain " + appName);
                            });
                    });

                var task2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(
                    () =>
                    {
                        RemoteAction.Invoke(
                            context2.Domain,
                            () =>
                            {
                                var appName = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ApplicationName;
                                Console.WriteLine("Hello from app domain " + appName);
                            });
                    });

                // Be sure to wait, else the domains will dispose
                Task.WaitAll(task1, task2);
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

More information is available here: https://github.com/jduv/AppDomainToolkit

Answer (score 2):

Wrap the cross-domain calls it with any of the general-purpose asynchronous execution mechanisms, and probably wait until all the calls finish. E.g.

```
Parallel.ForEach(appDomains, domain => domain.DoCallBack(new CrossAppDomainDelegate(Event)));
```

or

```
var countDown = new CountdownEvent();
countDown.AddCount();
foreach (var domain in appdomains)
{
    countDown.AddCount();
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(_ =>
        {
            domain.DoCallBack(new CrossAppDomainDelegate(Event));
            countDown.Signal();
        });
}

countDown.Signal();
countDown.Wait();
```